# ora-00604 : error occured at ecursive SQL level 1?

Tags: java, oracle

I have java code written using Java 6 and ojdbc14.jar to connect to my oracle database and trying to get sequence id using below code:

```
long lNewAuditId = 0;

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result = null;

    try {
        stmt = argConnection.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeQuery(SQL_NEXT_AUDIT_ID);

        if ( !result.next() )
            throw new DAOException("Error obtaining new Audit Id - no result");

        lNewAuditId = result.getLong(1);
        m_logger.debug("Next Audit Id: " + lNewAuditId);

    } 
    catch (SQLException sqle) 
    {
        throw new DAOException("Error getting next Audit id", sqle);            
    } 
    finally 
    {
        // do not close the connection here
        close(result);
        close(stmt);
    }
```

I hope I am closing stmt properly. While running this code, I am facing the below issue:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:957)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1062)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.java:841)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1134)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1274)
```

Comment: You do not show your statement, your `close()` method, the actual place where your exception is generated, so it is hard to give an answer. Your code does however look innocent. I would list the cursors in the database. Can also be a driver bug (for example getTables of DB meta data had a cursor leak in 12.1.0.2 drivers).

Comment: your query generates some recursive calls. Besides, in the log we see an executeUpdate() method called while you invoke executeQuery() in your code. Why ? Maybe your query could explain that. So, you should show the query and the **whole** stacktrace.

Comment: I added correct log over here. and my close method is closing the stmt by calling stmt.close(). My database is Oracle 12c and Java version 1.6 and using ojdbc14.jar.

Comment: 600 errors generally mean there's a problem that occurred between Oracle and the underlying O/S.  Check the oracle log - it will generally have either other errors or some hex code that indicates to support what the type of problem was.  It's usually not a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the underlying error, it says:

> ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Oracle throws this error when it can't allocate a `cursor` to your query. In the context of Java, cursor is mapped to `resultSet` object, so this typically means you have a `resultSet` leak somewhere in your application.

In the above example, `close()` method is called in `finally` block, and assuming it closes the `resultSet` (by invoing `close` method on `resultSet` object), you might need to look at the other areas of application and find out where `resultSet` or `preparedStatement` is not closed after executing the query.

If you have dba access, you can use the following query to get the open cursors:

```
select max(a.value) as highest_open_cur, p.value as max_open_cur
from v$sesstat a, v$statname b, v$parameter p
where a.statistic# = b.statistic# 
and b.name = 'opened cursors current'
and p.name= 'open_cursors'
group by p.value;
```